# Which OS (from stock) to act as an all-encompassing web application server for a java web app?

Tags: linux, mysql, ssh, web-server, java

I am about to purchase a hosting package from Jumba for a VPS. (http://www.jumba.com.au/vps)

They provide 3 options for OSes:

CentOS 5 64-bit

Debian 6.0 64-bit

Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit

Given these will all be stock, can you tell me which is the best server for me. Ideally, I want it to be the fastest OS, the most secure, the most minimal configuration, and the most straightforward to install and configure applications on. All it needs to run is Apache Tomcat, MySQL and SSH! (maybe Apache as well).

I know this does depend on my skill level with Linux. I have some patchy experience with Ubuntu and Red Hat, and know my way round a command line.

...or is it all much of a muchness?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use what you're most comfortable with.** If you're equally comfortable with them all (or uncomfortable as the case may be), IMO I'd say use CentOS as it is based on "a prominent North American Enterprise Linux vendor", has a decent amount of packages, is very stable and has plenty of tutorials to perform exactly what you're planning on doing.

Then again, the same could be said for Debian and Ubuntu. You can't exactly go *wrong* with any of them. Throw their logos up on a dartboard, throw a dart and get to building The Next Amazing Web App.

Comment: Sweet! That's what I choose too when I first needed a web server. =)